# Error during creation of Chains (Clusters) using hyperledger cello with docker agent

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I am trying to create a cluster (Chain) within a Host using hyperledger-cello, but got error during the process. When containers created below error is thrown in Master node log and containers stoped and removed immediately.

```
cello-operator-dashboard | ERROR: for 3a526684ce284b63b94fc57ed6ec40e1_cli  Cannot start service cli: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/opt/cello/fabric-1.0/solo/configtx.yaml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5e41d6d6f580226e5577f4b2345a278246b6e206905e8496acd75c1c411ff3b6/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5e41d6d6f580226e5577f4b2345a278246b6e206905e8496acd75c1c411ff3b6/merged/etc/hyperledger/fabric/configtx.yaml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Anyone faced similar issue?

Host List Page:
[image: Host List Page]

Creating Chains(Clusters):
[image: Creating Chains(Clusters)]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is thrown by Docker. It happens when docker attempts to mount a file, In your case the file `/opt/cello/fabric-1.0/solo/configtx.yaml`.
Watch out when verifying the file because when mounting a bind-type file that does not exist, Docker will create a folder with the file name if no file exists.

Check if something exists at `/opt/cello/fabric-1.0/solo/configtx.yaml` and if it is a folder remove it, Depending on what generates the file you might need to reinstall cello.

Answer (score 0):

We had clean up the dangling volumes and restart docker